# SQL Server return distinct rows?

Tags: sql-server

I'm running this SQL statement:

```
SELECT   
    s.indx, S.custid, S.date, S.qty, S.item, S.price, S.extprice, 
    S.salestax, S.linetotal, S.salenbr, C.company, P.MOP
FROM            
    sales S
JOIN
    cust C ON S.custid = C.custid
JOIN
    pmts P ON S.salenbr = p.salenbr
WHERE        
    (s.salenbr = 16749)
```

It's returning this result set:

```
indx    custid  date    qty item    price   extprice    salestax    linetotal   salenbr company MOP
170835  695 2021-09-27 10:00:44.000 1.00    1X4X12  7.85    7.85    0.75    8.60    16749   COUNTER SALE    CS   
170835  695 2021-09-27 10:00:44.000 1.00    1X4X12  7.85    7.85    0.75    8.60    16749   COUNTER SALE    CC   
170836  695 2021-09-27 10:00:44.000 1.00    1X6X12  11.62   11.62   1.10    12.72   16749   COUNTER SALE    CS   
170836  695 2021-09-27 10:00:44.000 1.00    1X6X12  11.62   11.62   1.10    12.72   16749   COUNTER SALE    CC
```

I want to just pull the rows where the method of payment "MOP" is different. I'm using the data to run a report and need it just with distinct or unique MOP's.

Thank You

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Your sample results are meaningless without the context of source data, however column `MOP` appears to already be distinct, so what exactly is wrong with the results?

Comment: Which one of the two MOP='CS' and of the two MOP='CC' records do you want to return?

Comment: No one but you knows your schema and the relationships between the tables. Presumably you have a 1:M relationship between sale and pmts - resulting in what only look like duplicates. If you had included more columns from pmts it would be more obvious. It also seems that sales represents what most would call a "detail" table. A given "transaction" is represented by multiple rows containing the same value for salenbr. Your payment is directly associated to the "transation" but you artifically associated to sales (the detail) - the crux of your problem. Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here an arbitrarily take the "first" record from each `MOP` group, according to some order:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT s.indx, S.custid, S.date, S.qty, S.item, S.price, S.extprice, 
           S.salestax, S.linetotal, S.salenbr, C.company, P.MOP,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.MOP ORDER BY S.date) rn
    FROM sales S
    INNER JOIN cust C ON S.custid = C.custid
    INNER JOIN pmts P ON S.salenbr = P.salenbr
    WHERE S.salenbr = 16749
)

SELECT indx, custid, date, qty, item, price, exitprice,
       salestax, linetotal, salenbr, company, MOP
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want to do will probably work better using a Common Table Expression or CTE. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE_Sales AS
(
    SELECT
        s.indx, S.custid, S.date, S.qty, S.item, S.price, S.extprice, 
        S.salestax, S.linetotal, S.salenbr, C.company, P.MOP, 
        COUNT(1) AS salesCount
    FROM
        sales S
    JOIN
        cust C ON S.custid = C.custid
    JOIN
        pmts P ON S.salenbr = p.salenbr
    GROUP BY
        s.indx, S.custid, S.date, S.qty, S.item, S.price, S.extprice,
        S.salestax, S.linetotal, S.salenbr, C.company, P.MOP
)
SELECT     
    indx, custid, date, qty, item, price, extprice, 
    salestax, linetotal, salenbr, company 
FROM
    CTE_Sales
GROUP BY 
    indx, custid, date, qty, item, price, extprice, 
    salestax, linetotal, salenbr, company
HAVING 
    salesCount > 1
```

What this does is that the CTE contains all your data, which makes it easier to not deal with joins every time. You've also done a group by so you know how many records you have for the same sale.

Then, when you pull the data, you're grouping the records without the MOP. Since the first record is grouped with MOP and the second is grouped without, you know that the MOPs are different.

Comment: Added the `FROM CTE_Sales` to the final `SELECT`  ...

Answer (score 0):

Me thinks I need to go back and do some redesigning in my code and data tables  SMor you are correct about the details vs. the transactions. Live and learn :)   Thanks to you all for taking the time to respond. I work solo so It's always great to hear other comments and ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use the answer box to post thanks. You can use comments, and upvote answers to thank them.